# How could I reuse protobuf memory without reallocating it

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a protobuf message like this

```
message ImgReply {  
  bytes data = 1;    
}
```

And I want to assign its contents with `set_allocated` method:

```
string *buf = new string();
GRPC_CALL_BACK_FUNCTION() {

    .....
    reply->set_allocated_data(buf);
    return Status::OK;
}
```

Now each time the grpc function is call, the `buf` will be released automatically. I would like to reuse it such that I do not need to reallocate memory each time. I tried to call the `reply->release_data();` method will just clear the `data` field and the client would receive no data at all. So how could I reuse this `buf` variable and do not let protobuf delete it automatically please ?

Answer (score 0):

The gRPC C++ sync API doesn't provide any feature for custom memory allocation. The callback API has been planned with a message allocator feature, but that hasn't been de-experimentalized yet, so it isn't ready to use publicly. That should be available within the next month or two.